# Macbook air, 11 inches backlight not working after lcd replacement

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, backlight

I just replaced the screen of my macbook air and now the **backlight** does not work. When I turn on the laptop, the screen works but the backlight does not turn on. I've tested with a couple of screens but no success.

Is the problem with the backlight LED, or fuse or logic board, is there any solution?

**Model: Macbook air, 11 inches model A1370, 2011.**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a much better vantage point than us on the internet to guess.

First, reconnect all cables and hope it's that.

If not, you'll need to start replacing parts one by one. The odds of a new LCD being faulty are low - but the circumstances of the repair might help.

Was the LCD out the reason you swapped the panel?

You might need a second machine to isolate each part - test whether it's the cable, inverter, logic board LCD or something else.

Comment: Hi I reconnected the two cables in the lcd converter board and connect them again, it didnt work. I think the lcd is ok. I have not yet opened the case to access the logic board etc. I think the problem could be with supply voltage to the backlight. I dont know if this model is similar to other macbooks that have WLED and fuse, any idea? is there any documentation, picture of the boards available? thanks

Comment: Unless it's documented on iFixit.com, you might need to get help from an Apple authorized repair center. I've had good luck going to them - explaining what I've done and letting them complete the repair. Some are more eager to help than others, so YMMV.

Comment: I can try that, but I'm not sure if they accept the laptop after I opened it myself

Comment: It's a grey area. If you put all the original pieces back and tell them you tried a repair but failed - they can check your work. If you didn't break things further, they won't have to charge you extra to fix that. If you did mess things up, they'll let you know and quote extra to fix.

Answer (score -1):

The backlight cable to the lcd control board is connected wrong way round. Common mistake.